# What is Alternative for asp:panel in asp.net mvc

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to convert it into asp:net panel to mvc. Is there any way to convert 
This is my html code:

```
<asp:Panel ID="MessagePanel" runat="server" CssClass="Set" Visible="false">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Panel is rendered into div. So:

```
<div id="MessagePanel" class="Set" style="display: none;" />
```